# How to create a table showing the occurrence of a list words in the title and description columns from a Kaggle csv file using Python

Tags: python

I am new to coding with Python and I am having trouble figuring out ...

How to create a table showing the occurrence of a list words in the title and description columns from a Kaggle csv file using Python.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/victorsoeiro/netflix-tv-shows-and-movies

title.csv

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_csv(r'\PATH\titles.csv') 

royal = (['crown', 'queen', 'king', 'prince', 'princess', 'royal', 'majesty', 'monarchy', 'sovereignty', 'throne', 'command', 'kingdom', 'dutch', 'dutchess'])

small_df2 = df2[['title','description']]

small_df2['total'] = df2.title.str.lower().apply(str.split).apply(lambda x:len(set(words) & set(x)))

royaltitles = pd.Series(' '.join(['title']).lower().split()).value_counts()

#table of title and description with words from royal list.

royaltitles_table = ?  small_df2

print(royaltitles_table)
```

Comment: How does the posted code relate to your question?

Comment: I'm a beginner and shared my progress. I'm not sure how to search for the words in my 'royal' list and view the rows that contain the words in my list.

Comment: Take a look at this example. I think it can help you https://www.kaggle.com/code/yhuan95/word-frequency-time-series-in-news-headlines/notebook